# Approximate $f(x)= x^2$ with the best approximation in $L_1$ under the given norm.

Tags: numerical-methods, normed-spaces, inner-products, numerical-linear-algebra, approximation-theory

The given norm is: $||f||= \sqrt{A_0 |f(x_0)|^2 + A_1 |f(x_1)|^2 + A_2 |f(x_2)|^2}$
And from a previous question I have found the following:

$A_0 = \frac {-\sqrt{\pi/3}}{2}$

$A_1 = \frac {\sqrt{\pi/3}}{2}$

$A_2 = \sqrt{\pi}$

$x_0 = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$

$x_1 = -\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$

$x_2 = -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$

Now my plan of work is the following:

1. Choosing an orthogonal basis
2. Identifying the induced inner product
3. Building the system of equations and solving it

My problem is finding the inner product induced from a norm, I know how to find the norm of an inner product but not the opposite. Maybe there’s a different way to solve the question that differs from my plan of work? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all, a norm doesn't always arise from an inner product. It is the case though if the norm satisfies the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law).** In that case, the inner product can be derived from the norm using the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity). That is for real normed spaces:

$$\langle x, y \rangle = \frac{1}{4}\left(\Vert x+y \Vert^2 - \Vert x - y \Vert^2\right).$$